# Prove that $Q/Z$ is not isomorphic to a proper subgroup of itself?

Tags: group-theory

How can we define a general subgroup of $Q/Z$ , based on which we can extend the properties?

Comment: **Hint**: If you've covered it, then the first isomorphism theorem may be useful.

Answer (score 4):

For each $n$, $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ has exactly $\varphi(n)$ elements of order $n$, which have to be in the image of the isomorphism. But those elements generate $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ (each $1/n$ is among them), so the image is $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ itself.